# PySpark - When Otherwise - Condition should be a Column

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe as below

```
root
 |-- tasin: string (nullable = true)
 |-- advertiser_id: decimal(38,10) (nullable = true)
 |-- predicted_sp_sold_units: decimal(38,10) (nullable = true)
 |-- predicted_sp_impressions: decimal(38,10) (nullable = true)
 |-- predicted_sp_clicks: decimal(38,10) (nullable = true)
 |-- predicted_sdc_sold_units: decimal(38,10) (nullable = true)
 |-- predicted_sdc_impressions: decimal(38,10) (nullable = true)
 |-- predicted_sdc_clicks: decimal(38,10) (nullable = true)
 |-- predicted_sda_sold_units: decimal(38,10) (nullable = true)
 |-- predicted_sda_impressions: decimal(38,10) (nullable = true)
 |-- predicted_sda_clicks: decimal(38,10) (nullable = true)
 |-- region_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- marketplace_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- dataset_date: date (nullable = true)
```

Now I am using the below select statement. I am looking for presence of a column name and if present select the value or else fill with Null. The dataframe is stored in df variable.

```
scores_df1 = df.select(
            col('marketplace_id'),
            col('region_id'),
            col('tasin'),
            col('advertiser_id'),
            col('predicted_sp_sold_units'),
            col('predicted_sp_impressions'),
            col('predicted_sp_clicks'),
            col('predicted_sdc_sold_units'),
            col('predicted_sdc_impressions'),
            col('predicted_sdc_clicks'),
            col('predicted_sda_sold_units'),
            col('predicted_sda_impressions'),
            col('predicted_sda_clicks'),
            when('sdcr_score' in df.columns is True, col('sdcr_score')).otherwise(lit(None)).alias('sdcr_score'),
            when('sdar_score' in df.columns is True, col('sdar_score')).otherwise(lit(None)).alias('sdar_score')
    )
```

I am receiving error <class 'TypeError'>: condition should be a Column

Please advice what is wrong

Answer (score 1):

the phrase `'sdcr_score' in df.columns is True` is evaluated in Python before moving to spark and return True/False.
So what you are passing to spark is: when(True, ..., ...).

When is expecting the first argument to be a Column that is evaluated to a True/False statement and not a Pythonic Bool.

You can wrap the argument with `lit()` function which will basically pass a True/False column to all arguments of the when clause.